.Problem with randomization of Instances in a Repeat Zone
Hello everyone, my project is still to animate a growth of branches on a trunk and other branches on the firsts and so on…
I want to randomize the position of the branches to do so, in the Groupe Node called Branches, I use two opposite branches in a collection. I measure the Domaine Size, subtract one and put this value in the Max Value socket of a Random node, then use it as the Instances Index of a Instances on Points.
What’s puzzle me is that’s working well on the first pass of the Repeat Zone but not on the second iteration: It change of orientation constantly during the growth.


Thank you for your help.

Since your Random Value is inside your Repeat Zone, it will be recalculated at each frame. One possibility would be to save this random value as an attribute when creating a new branch.

Thanks Lutzi I, will try that.

@Lutzi I don't see How to do that... Could you be more explicit? Thank you.

I'm having a hard time understanding and adapting your blend file. Problem is, at each frame you recalculate everything (including Random Value), where this random pick of branch should be unique and for example computed at first frame. Maybe use a Noise Texture to get a unique value based on position ? Here is an example (only works the second generation of branches) https://blend-exchange.com/b/g5AwjPJX/.

@Lutzi it work with the second generation , the third and so on... I didn't know this technique, I think it's a good way to do things. Thanks a lot.

My pleasure. The idea is to be sure this random value doesn't change. After a bit more thoughts, I would recommend using a White Noise Texture instead (infinitely fine noise texture). Also, now in Blender 4.1 you can display attributes in the viewport. Super useful.

@Lutzi switch the plug to color it work even with the first generation (it's position after all). thanks again Lutzi.
